# C# - How to get dependent combobox values from custom classes

Tags: c#, wpf, list, combobox

I have a list `ListForTesting` of type `TestID`.

```
 List<HelpClass.TestID> ListForTesting;

    //Populating the list
    HelpClass.TestID TestObject = new HelpClass.TestID();
    .
    .
    //data here
    .
    .
    TestObject.Manoeuvres = new List<HelpClass.ManoeuvresID>();
    HelpClass.ManoeuvresID Manoeuvre = new HelpClass.ManoeuvresID();
    .
    .
    //more data here
    .
    .
TestObject.Manoeuvres.Add(Manoeuvre);
ListForTesting.Add(TestObject);
```

I am using that list to get a dropdown list in a combobox

```
combobox_testType.ItemsSource = ListForTesting.Select(t => t.testName);
```

Then I have another combobox which is dependent on the first one and I would like to have something like the following.

```
combobox_manouevre.ItemsSource = ListForTesting[selectedindexfromfirstcombobox].Manoeuvres.Select(t => t.manName);
```

Comment: anyone? need some help here

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do :

```
combobox1.ItemsSource = ListForTesting;
combobox1.DisplayMember= "testName";
combobox1.ValueMember= "id";
```

and in the selectedChanged event of combobox1 :

```
combobox2.ItemsSource = ListForTesting.Where(x => x.id == combobox1.SelectedValue).Manoeuvres;
combobox2.DisplayMember= "manName";
combobox2.ValueMember= "idManoeuvre";
```

Comment: it tells me that "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'object'"  this is in WPF

Comment: I've fixed by `x.testName == combobox_testType.SelectedValue.ToString()` but cannot get the last part `.Manoeuvres` working

Comment: In your example you have 2 different combobox, right ?
Why both are named "combobox_testType" ? Error of copy/paste or is it like this in your code ?
Can you show me your code with your modifications ?

Comment: @c.changon you were right the copy/paste was wrong. Could you please help now?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the most appropriate answer but it did work in the second combobox.

`combobox_manouevre.ItemsSource = ListForTesting.Where(x => x.testName == combobox_testType.SelectedValue.ToString()).SelectMany(l=>l.Manoeuvres).Select(o=>o.manName);`

Answer (score 0):

For more visibility in your code you can do this :

```
combobox_manouevre.ItemsSource = ListForTesting.Where(x => x.testName == combobox_testType.SelectedValue.ToString()).FirstOrDefault().Manoeuvres;
combobox_manouevre.DisplayMember = "manName";
combobox_manouevre.ValueMember = "yourIdManoeuvre";
```

It's more safe to use the DisplayMember and ValueMember for separating the displayed value in your combobox and the value (id)..

For example :

List of manœuvre :

```
id= 1 name= "manoeuvre1"  
id= 2 name= "manoeuvre1" // (same name that id=1)  
id= 3 name= "manoeuvre2"
```

if you select the second "manoeuvre1", the id will be 2 and you will work with this id (no chance of being wrong)

Same thing for your list ListForTesting

Comment: In WPF,  
DisplayMember = DisplayMemberPath  and 
ValueMember = SelectedValuePath.